# Why are ADR values lower than actual stocks listed on BSE/NSE?

Tags: adr

Why are ADR values lower than actual stock?

For example if we look at Infosys ADR it has given around 9-10% growth in stock price, over last 5 years.
Whereas if we look at actual stock listed on NSE/BSE for same 5 years period then it has given 163.29% growth in the stock price.

A similar phenomenon could be observed for HDFCBank ADR price vs. HDFCBank NSE stock price

So what is the benefit of investing through ADR if its not passing the actual value increase in the stock.

Thanks

Comment: What currency is each listing in?

Comment: NSE/BSE listings are in INR. and corresponding ADR in USD

Comment: So, what's the growth when you account for currency conversion?  Exchange rates change over time.

Comment: Can you share your data? If I look up Infosys, it was at 600 in Jan 18 and is now at 1500. Infosys ADR was at 9 in Jan 18 and is now at 19.

Comment: @Solarflare could you please check for HDFCBank:NSE vs HDFCBank ADR as well and let me know your view? For Infosys I have checked Google Finance chart for 5-years. thanks

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for comment. But isn't ADR there to safeguard against currency fluctuation? Also, I don't see INR exponentioally devalued against USD in last 5 years for ADR to give just 9% growth as against 163.29% growth by underlying security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ADR will show the same gain as the original stock, as it can be considered the same stock. (This is ignoring some details that become relevant when e.g. Russian ADRs get sanctioned.) Any difference will be fixed by arbitrage effects (given enough volume).

However, to directly compare the gains, you have to include the currency effect. The Indian Rupie lost ~20% against the USD in the last 5 years, so the gain of the ADR in USD will of course be lower (e.g. if the original stock would not have moved at all in the last 5 years, the ADR would have lost 20%).

If you only have a 9% gain for the ADR, you might have some wrong data though. You mentioned in the comments that you are are using Google Finance, and for the Infosys ADR, I see a gain of 103% in 5 years, not 9-10%, so check your data:

- [Google Finance Infosys NSE 5y chart](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/INFY:NSE?window=5Y): 571 INR in 2018, 1527 INR today, 167% gain.
- [Google Finance Infosys ADR NYSE 5y chart](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/INFY:NYSE?window=5Y): 9.25$ in 2018, 18.81$ today, 103% gain.
- [Google Finance INR/USD 5y chart](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/INR-USD?window=5Y): 0.0157 in 2018, 0.0123 today, 21.5% loss.

Correcting the gain for the currency loss, the gain of the original stock in USD is 167%*78.5%-21.5%=110%.

Since the dates of the charts do not match exactly (the first chart starts on 2.2.2018, the second on 26.1.2018), the remaining difference should be due to slightly different dates.

Your other example, the HDFC Bank, has the same behaviour: [70% on NSE](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/HDFCBANK:NSE?window=5Y), [29% for the ADR](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/HDB:NYSE?window=5Y), so including the currency effect the gain in INR translates to 70%*78.5%-21.5%=33.5% in USD. The small difference can be again attributed to the date mismatches.